# JQuery "show" not displaying the right display style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I have created some kind of gallery with php code. I wanted to animate going to the next set of pictures with JQuery `hide()` and `show()`. The problem is that when I show the next set of pictures, the pictures aren't showing next to each other anymore but in a vertical row.

The original display type is "inline-block", but when I put the css function after the animate function, the animation looks weird.

I tried creating a JsFiddle but The Javascript part doesn't seems to be working http://jsfiddle.net/P3gty/

This is my code:
Javascript

```
function changeGallery(count)
{

  currentpage+=count;

  for(var i=0;i<numpics;i++)
  {
    //document.getElementById("galpic"+(i)).style.display = "none";
    $("#galpic"+(i)).hide(animationtype,animationspeed);
  }


  for(var i=0;i<8  && ((currentpage*8))+i<numpics;i++)
  {
    //document.getElementById("galpic"+(i+(currentpage*8))).style.display = "block";
    $("#galpic"+(i+(currentpage*8))).delay(animationspeed).show(animationtype,animationspeed);
  }

  disableButtons();

}
```

css

```
.thumb
{
    border:solid black .1em;

  display: inline-block;
}
```

html

```
<div id="thumbcontainer">
<ul id="pictures">

<!-- Multiple echos of -->
<li id='galpic$imagecount'><a href='img/gallery/".$file."'rel='lightbox[".$lightbox."]'>
<img src="img/thumbs/'.$file.'" alt="Picture" class="thumb" />
</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: can you share your html too - or better yet a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: also - your solution may be as simple as using `float: left;` instead of `display: inline-block;`

Comment: You are using PHP addidtion operator (dot): `"#galpic".concat(i)` Replace that with "+" when writing javascript. ;) Also there is no global `concat` method in JS. PHP !== JS

Comment: Thanks for the tip! And yes I have tried using float left, but the problem is my images arent really centered that way... I will also add the html code

Comment: By default, jquery .show() using "display: block;" property. It can restore previous css settings, like inline-block, but in your css "display: inline-block;" is added only for images with class .thumb, not for li elements. Try to add "display: inline-block;" for "#pictures>li" (but still, there is not enough information without jsfiddle)

Comment: Tried making a JsFiddle but I can't get it to run, the code is a bit complex to copy. Also I tried adding display inline-block but it's still not working